# Folder created in one step of DockerFile is not available in later steps

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to dockerize a flask application but before I spin up the server I need to make sure some of the files are available. These files are stored in Google Cloud Storage. A script is written that will fetch the data from GCP and store it in a folder. The final step is to run app.py but the created folder is not present during this step. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /backend

# All python packages needed for this project are put in this file
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# This script currently connects to GCP cloud storage
# fetch the required file
# create a folder and store the fetched file in that folder
RUN python3 setup.py

CMD ["python3", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: What folder isn't available when you run it? What is the exactly error message you're getting? How are you running this image?

Comment: @larsks Data in CSV files are stored in Cloud storage and the job of setup.py is to create a folder and copy all the CSV files to that folder. Once this step is completed, app.py (flask server) will perform some operations on those files. These operations cannot be performed because the folder is not created and there are no errors.

Comment: I mean, you're comments are suggesting that setup.py is creating the folder so the problem is with your script and not the dockerfile...

Comment: @alex067 when I ran setup.py seperately, it worked. The same command also runs successfully in docker build, but when I log into the container I can't see the folder.

Comment: I would highly suggest you re-think how this works. A dockerfile is designed to create your environment, and not run setup tasks like fetching csv data that your app depends on. 

You really should be running your setup script in your CMD as a pre-task to your initial server startup.